# Leading a campus ministry group addressing pornography addiction while also serving as a professor

Tags: religious-issues, extracurricular

**Context**: I am a math professor at a small Christian college in the US.

Shortly after starting my undergraduate education, I made choices that lead me to an addiction to internet pornography, and that addiction grew considerably worse in graduate school.  Exposure to this content deeply affected the way that I looked at and perceived women, and I have invested considerable time and effort into healing the psychological damage resulting from my behavior.  I hid this addiction very effectively throughout my education and early career and never truly began dealing with the problem and its roots until shortly after I was married several years later.  (My wife has been immensely and undeservedly gracious, patient, and wise throughout the whole process.  I could say much more, but that's not relevant to my question.)

Now that I am sufficiently into my recovery, I am building a healthier vision for my future.  In particular, I feel called to help undergraduate men who are struggling similarly to how I did all those years ago.  I know that a campus ministry group related to sexual addiction would have been a serious blessing to me at the time, and I would like to consider starting one.  I plan to meet with a representative from our campus ministry office (and potentially my department chair) about this when the time is right, but I wanted to ask this question here first.

**Question**:
Would it be possible to lead a group aimed at helping young men who struggle with sexual addiction while also serving as a professor at my institution?  This group would probably operate with internal confidentiality, but I know that in the course of leading the group that I will need to disclose a nontrivial amount of my personal history.  This would include ugly details about the extent of my pornography use and the objectification of many of the women who I studied with as a undergraduate and taught in graduate school and my early career.  In particular, I am concerned about how this information could affect my career or standing among both my colleagues and students at the college if the confidentiality of the group is not respected.  Even if the confidentiality of the group is respected, should I be concerned about the likelihood that a student from the group might end up in one of my classes?

Although my college is indeed a Christian institution, there are many faculty and students who are not practicing Christians or may even hold other faiths.  That said, I am interested in any and all opinions.

[Disclaimer: I realize that some people consider pornography use morally acceptable behavior, but for the sake of this question I am not interested in discussing the morality, necessity, or usefulness of the campus ministry group I described.]

**Clarifications**:

- Doing such a ministry outside of the university is an option, though more students would probably attend if it were on campus.
- I have previously volunteered in campus ministry, but have not yet done so as a professor.
- Most professors at my institution are quiet about their faith (or lack thereof); a few are very open about their Christianity. I'm not aware of any professors that are directly involved in student ministry.

Comment: Wow, that's a tough question. Congrats on your recovery in any case, and thanks for considering helping other suffering with similar addictions.

Comment: I think you should live under the assumption that anything that happens in that group will eventually become public knowledge in both oral and written form.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I suggest that you don't do this and leave it to professionals while you focus on teaching math and setting a good example for others.

If you have a dual role you are likely to confuse students, rather than to help them. Even revealing your past behavior could be an issue for many, both young women you are responsible for teaching and men who may or not share your past.

If you think such things need to be addressed at your institution, talk to the administration about hiring a trained professional. Addictions of all kinds likely need to be addressed, actually.

Note that I'd give the same advice to people at secular institutions.

And, for other addictions that I can think of the answer would probably remain the same. Some of your students may have suffered from addiction of others, say alcoholism in parents. It might make them less likely to trust you generally. If students come to you with concerns, refer them to a professional.

Comment: Strongly agree. OP, you're basically suggesting you tell the entire student body. "Hey, I struggled with a pornography addiction. Do you?? Come to my meeting." This would make me very uncomfortable in the same way a professor advertising their (former) drinking problem would.

Comment: This absolutely makes sense.  I am curious to see what other opinions or suggestions might appear, but it sounds like I will need to find a different setting (probably within a church) if I desire to help others facing similar issues.

Comment: @MathAnon  *(probably within a church)* why? the pornography issue runs across religions.

Comment: Strongly agree with this one. Groups like AA work because they are *anonymous*, a group where the facilitator is also in a position of authority (and many of the participants know and interact with not only the facilitator, but also each other, in other contexts) seems like a disaster in the making.

Comment: @EarlGrey It does indeed, but my recovery has been entirely dependent on my Christian faith.  I would feel comfortable walking alongside other Christians facing sexual addiction, but my experience wouldn't be much use to people with a different (or no) faith.

Comment: That is why professional are needed. I'd guess that everyone who overcomes any addiction has a personal and somewhat unique path. Professionals understand this sort of thing. What worked for you might not work for another.

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations on your sobriety!

There are self-help groups similar to Alcoholics Anonymous that address sex-addiction, namely SAA. I would suggest you seek them out with the view of setting up a new group on your campus. They would not want to be sponsored by campus ministry or the college, but they would accept room and maybe free coffee. After you participated in a few meetings and have found a sponsor with contact to the organization, you can then approach campus ministry.

Since they are anonymous and since the meetings are usually NOT open (you need to suffer from the problem addressed in order to attend a meeting), your privacy is somewhat guarded, though not absolutely protected. You should not be the convener anyway, as you are not qualified for addiction work.

You need to have the backing of campus ministry or someone high up in the administration, because there are probably morality clauses in your contract. Even though you are not violating them (You are NOT using for a long time), you do not want to appear to have violated them recently or that you are likely to violate them.

Addiction to pornography has become a big problem on campuses and in the work-force. Acting out can have close to career destroying effects, so that groups like the one you are contemplating are very useful. However, do not re-invent the wheel. The AA methodology works for motivated sufferers, but they had to learn how to do it. Similarly, sex addiction is a bit different than alcoholism, and you want to benefit from their collective knowledge.

You can of course go a very different route, trying to set up a Christian self-help group. Working with addiction is difficult, you are not trained, you do not have the relevant degrees, and you would expose yourself to ridicule that will make your other work very difficult. I would suggest that you do not do that since the chances of success are slim and the personal costs quite high. As you can see from one of the comments, your students might be queasy about your personal struggles.

Comment: I think that's an important point to highlight too: "feel[ing] called to help undergraduate men who are struggling similarly" does not actually make one *qualified* to provide help. It's not entirely clear how the balance between doing good and not being helpful is if someone with no background in treating addiction would run such a group.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand the following part of your answer correctly: *"there are probably morality clauses in your contract. Even though you are not violating them (You are NOT using for a long time)."* I'm having difficulties to imagine that an employer can forbid their employees the (private, of course) consumption of pornographic materials by including some clauses (be they about morality or whatever) in the contract. (Although my imagination might be overly limited in this respect; I continue to be surprised again and again by what certain laws say and what they don't say.)

Comment: Christian colleges in the US tend to restrict behavior of their faculty. Just like a Catholic hospital in Germany will not allow a chief officer remain in position if (s)he remarries. By admitting having a "sex problem", the original poster could expose himself/herself to sanctions.

Comment: @tschwarz: Yes, but my question is to what extent such restrictions are legally possible. Clearly, each jurisdiction will impose limits on which contracts are legally possible. Catholic hospitals in Germany (which also immediately came to my mind) is already a quite strong example of an employer interfering with things that are none of their business (although, interestingly, the Federal Constitutional Court doesn't seem to bother). Interferring with specific sexual practices of one's employees is even a more extreme example, so I'm wondering whether this is legally enforceable.

Comment: Whether morals clauses could prohibit private viewing of pornography is an interesting question; you might consider posting on [law.SE]. I find it very unlikely that OP could face sanctions in this case though; my experience with evangelical culture in the US is that it looks very favorably on those who successfully overcome past moral transgressions (which is not to say that professors discussing their sexual histories with students may not raise different concerns).

Answer (score 1):

Your desire to help others if commendable.

Confidentiality within a group may be violated, so please consider how public knowledge of your struggles with pornography addiction would make your female students and colleagues, present and future, feel in your presence (I am not justifying any such feelings). Maybe specifically ask women for their opinion.

Maybe you could find people who have led help-groups for pornography addiction, and ask them how their role has affected them.

Perhaps you could consider helping others in an online anonymous setting.

Comment: Also consider that the *participants* will often also know each other. How would OP react if it turns out that things that participants tell privately in group quickly turn to become campus rumors?